# react-redux-router won't navigate from saga using dispatched events. Middleware installed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

We have installed the middleware layer where we create the store

```
const sagaMiddleware = sagaMiddlewareFactory();
const routerMiddlewareInstance = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);
const logger = createLogger();
const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(
  // logger middleware needs to be last if you do not want all the logs of previous middleware
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, routerMiddlewareInstance, logger),
  persistState(
    window.location.href.match(
      /[?&]debug_session=([^&#]+)\b/
    )
  )
);

export default function configureStore(initialState: any) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("../reducers", () =>
      store.replaceReducer(require<any>("../reducers").default)
    );
  }

  return store;
}
```

and when we dispatch the navigate event:

```
  const nextPage: NavPage = newNav.pages[toIndex];
  const foo = push(nextPage.url);
  yield put(foo);
```

the application doesn't navigate.

Anyone have thoughts on this?  Are we not instantiating the middleware for navigation correctly?  It's similar, but not precisely like the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions) due to needing to also add the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `sagaMiddlewareFactory` function returns, but have you tried using `createSagaMiddleware` to create the middleware instead? Maybe that would help?

[createSagaMiddleware](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#createsagamiddlewareoptions)